# Ms SQL Server 2012 Bookmarks sharing / exporting

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

Is there a way to export or share my bookmarks in SQL code to other PC? If yes, please, tell me how to do it.

We are using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 v. 11.0.3000.0.

Comment: Yes that is possible

Comment: Thank you, @MrZach, could you please tell me, how to do it?